# Yii2 access to actions in new controllers

Tags: yii2, yii-url-manager, yii2-basic-app

Comrades, I have had issues implementing yii2 basic but I'm yet to give up. I have successfully installed yii2, activated pretty url and created the .htaccess file in the root folder. The Home, About, Contact and Login urlswork fine.

i. I have created a new model, InstTypes with the CRUD. Why does http://localhost:8081/we@ss/instTypes/create return Not Found (#404)?

ii. I have also created a module instClients. I can access the index action in the DefaultControler. I have a model Insts with its CRUD under this modules. Why does http://localhost:8081/we@ss/instClients/insts/create return Not Found (#404)?

I tend to think that this could be due to the removal of the import and autoload from the config.

Could someone demonstrate how they've created a new model and CRUD and successfully accessed its actions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[this](http://yii2-user.readthedocs.org/en/latest/basics/overriding-controllers.html) solved my problem. I needed to add the controllers to the controller map.

Answer (score 0):

> I have created a new model, InstTypes with the CRUD. Why does
>   http://localhost:8081/we@ss/instTypes/create return Not Found (#404)?

You cannot access a model directly, the only way to interact with a model is via a controller which will intern interact with the model and the view. By initializing the model $model = new YourModelNmae(); or by rendering a view.

From your URL

> http://localhost:8081/we@ss/instTypes/create

InstType should be your controller while create is an action under InstType

Using Yii2 Gii tool to generate a CRUD do the following : -

1. Generate your model
2. Generate your CRUD

go to

> http://localhost:8081/we@ss/yourController/YourActionOnYourController

Refer to this youtube link for more detail https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6B52-li6IgU

Happy coding :)

Comment: Appreciated a lot chapskev

Comment: If it help kindly pick it as an answer or upvote it. Hit me up if you have issues

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the other answers, your url isn't working because it's camelCase. You need to make it hyphenated, so

```
http://localhost:8081/we@ss/instTypes/create
```

will become

```
http://localhost:8081/we@ss/inst-types/create
```

You're getting the 404 because you're trying to access instTypes, it should be inst-types.